# How to provide 2 corda nodes with same legal name?

Tags: corda

How can we provide same legal name to 2 corda nodes.These corda nodes are used as a backup i.e when one node fails other node will carry out transaction with same legal name.

Answer (score 0):

For question regarding High-Availability question, please refer to the https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-enterprise/4.4/ha-utilities.html#ha-utilities

Currently for Open source version, we do not support 2 nodes having the same legal names.